# Special character ? in routes.MapRoute url parameter .Net MVC 4

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I made a new web site and I want to preserve old links just for doing a RedirectPermanent.
For that I wrote a new controller

```
public class RedirectController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Redirect/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return RedirectPermanent("~/");
    }
   ...
```

In RouteConfig.cs I wrote the routes as

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Redirect 301 prensa",
            url: "press.aspx", defaults: new { controller = "Redirect", action = "Index" }
        );
```

for redirect old urls cached on customers

My problem is when I want to put the special char "?" in url parameter

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Redirect 301 prensa",
            url: "press.aspx?id=1", defaults: new { controller = "Redirect", action = "Index" }
        );
```

App compiles ok but crash starting saying Url can't contain an ? character

My web.config is like

```
<httpRuntime requestPathInvalidCharacters="&lt;,&gt;,*,%,&amp;,\" requestValidationMode="2.0"/>
<pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0" validateRequest="false"/>
```

Any ideas for writing special chars?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should try to reconfigure your route mapping and group both routes with a wildcard expression:

```
routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Redirect 301 prensa",
        url: "{press.aspx*}", defaults: new { controller = "Redirect", action = "Index" }
    );
```

by this way, the urls related (press.aspx, press.asx?id=1 press.asxpAnything) will be redirected to the same place.

And check requestPathInvalidCharacters in your web.config to allow the use of the characters '?' and probably '&'.